# Resolve await in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to get the valid jwt token for an async method using await.
How to resolve await isValid in function?

```
  module.exports.resolveAfter2Seconds =  async function resolveAfter2Seconds(jwt) {
       const cert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + ‘/...’);  // get public key
       let a =  await isValid(jwt, cert)
    };

    async function isValid(jwt, cert) {
       return jwtWebToken.verify(jwt, cert, function (err, decoded) {
           console.log(decoded);
           if (! decoded) {
               throw new Error(“error”);
           }

           return decoded;
       })
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out the following code.

```
function isValid(jwt, cert) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    jwtWebToken.verify(jwt, cert, function (err, decoded) {
      if (! decoded) {
          throw new Error(“error”);
      }

      resolve(decoded)
    })
  });
}
```